# How to conditionally skip maven tests on Jenkins for CI

Tags: git, maven, testing, jenkins, continuous-integration

We use GitLab and Jenkins for CI. Whenever a merge request is approved to `master` branch, GitLab sends a request to Jenkins to run a build job which, upon successful completion, deploys to tomcat.

The build job checks out files from gitlab `master`branch, builds the project by using `clean install`, and saves artifacts.

There are many cases when commits are property file updates, html view file updates, and we don't really have any tests for those files.

I know there is a switch to skip all tests during `mvn clean install`, but is there any way to conditionally skip test if the commits only include files that are css, js, properties, html, etc.?

Thanks!

Comment: What about making a separate module for those things `css, js, html, properties`?

Comment: @khmarbaise, we have multiple modules in the same "mother" project in the same GitLab repo. Any changes to any of the modules triggers the maven build.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [Jenkins GIT plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) then you can refer within build to current and previous build last commits with GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT and GIT_COMMIT variables. Combine it with git diff command to have list of all modified files since previous build:

```
git diff --name-only $GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT $GIT_COMMIT
```

Next using ***grep*** command, you can check if there are any files with other extensions than one mentioned by you. If so, you can execute proper Maven command line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a environment variable includes not just the previous commit, but all commits in the merge request?

Comment: @Jason What do you exactly mean by _"merge request"_? _"request"_ isn't mentioned in [git-merge](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-merge). Anyway, [no, there isn't](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-Environmentvariables).

Comment: @GeriBroser in GitLab, after `git push origin` a few commits from a dev branch, the developer can submit a "merge request" into master. After the reviewer approves the merge request, GitLab merges the commits into master and pings Jenkins to kick off a build.

Comment: @Jason I see. Thx for the explanation. If the commits in the merge request are consecutive on master GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT should be what you want: _"the previous **built** commit from the same branch"_ Or maybe there is an option in GitLab to [squash the merge commits](http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/78474/Git--squash-last-3-commits-together/)?

Answer (score 1):

Following [@PiotrOktaba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26414586/1744774) (line breaks in commands for better readability):

```
~/git/test  (master)$ git diff --name-only $GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT $GIT_COMMIT
test.txt

~/git/test  (master)$ git diff --name-only $GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT $GIT_COMMIT |
    grep -vE '.*\.css|.*\.js|.*\.properties|.*\.html|.*\.txt' | wc -l
      0
```

No other files than the given are in the commit → skip tests.

```
~/git/test  (master)$ git diff --name-only $GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT $GIT_COMMIT
test.java
test.txt

~/git/test  (master)$ git diff --name-only $GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT $GIT_COMMIT |
    grep -vE '.*\.css|.*\.js|.*\.properties|.*\.html|.*\.txt' | wc -l 
      1
```

A file different to the given is in the commit → don't skip tests.

Use this in a conditional build step that checks for the return value of a Bash script.